# Mouseenter event triggered in chrome when resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Very strange behaviour in Google Chrome !

I've got a grid of `div` , and on each of then, I add an eventListenner for `mouseenter` event. In my demo code, when the event is triggered the div get `opacity:0.2`.

```
$(".target_div_class").on("mouseenter",  [my action ...])
```

Well, it's work's on every browser except in Google Chrome.

To reproduce the strange behaviour in chrome, [go to my codepen demo page](http://codepen.io/_larry_/pen/yscqn) place the mouse pointer in front of the grid and start to resize the main browser windows quickly, you will see that some of the divs get opacity changed even if there is not mouse roll-over  !

what I'm doing wrong, is an special jquery event that Chrome doesn't like ?

thank's

larry

**edit -1-**

I think I understand why some `div` receive the event.

It seem's that, when I click on a border (left or right) of the browser, Chrome keep a trace of the mouse position X and Y.

Then when slowly expand the browser width, any `div` that under this "start mouse position" receive the event.
It is really simple to reproduce when first the browser width is thin, and then slowly expand it, if I take a pen and place it at the mouse start position before resize, It's clear. very very strange.

**edit -2-**

This behaviour is only **on a OS windows 8**, I've just test it on a Mac , and there is not problems !

Well, I've been testing this behaviour on a couple of sites, like this one :https://devart.withgoogle.com/

made by Google professional I suppose, and the strange behaviour occurs again, I'll try to find how to contact Google Chrome team ...

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that mouseenter/mouseleave is fully supported by chrome. Chrome only simulates those functions, unlike in IE.

But, the problem only occurs when someone tries to re-size the window faster than the browser's edge actually moves and the mouse goes into the page momentarily. So, its not that unreasonable a behavior. You could always try to fix it with a

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //some code to reset opacity
});
```

Comment: Senju , well, I've juste make a test with the "mouseover' instead of the "mouseenter" and there is the same behavior. With your Answer in mind I'll try to find a workaround but it's like a hack to something very basic. You know sometimes , even if I do not resize windows very quickly , an event is triggered ....

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
$(".target_div_class").on("mouseenter", function(){
 event.stopPropagation();
   //your code
});
```

Comment: Some details of the event object and stopPropagation() function, with links to documentation in particular would be a good improvement to this answer.

Comment: @Abhishek Verma , no same behaviour, see my edited first question and I've discover how certain div receive event ! it's very very strange